# how to pass arguments to a decorator in a class

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-decorators

I have a unit test that loads some data in the database to test against.
I have created a decorator function for this, to be used on a test case

```
class TestCompany(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ...
        self.engine = create_engine(db_url)
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = Session() 


    @loadfixtures(['employee.json'])
    def test_checkdb_employee(self):
        c = self.session.query(Employee).count()
        self.assertEqual(c , 20)
```

However, I need to somehow pass `self.engine` to the decorator.

`@loadfixtures(self.engine, ['employee.json'])` does not work, because `self` is not available there.

I created this solution for this, but is there a simpler (more readable) solution?

```
    def test_checkdb_employee(self):
        @loadfixtures(['employee.json'])
        def run(engine):
            c = self.session.query(Employee).count()
            self.assertEqual(c , 20)
        return run(self.engine)

     
#decorator
import pandas as pd
 
def loadfixtures( files):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            for file in files: 
                df = pd.read_json(Path(datafolder).joinpath(file))
                df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], con=args[0],index=False, if_exists='append')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_func
    return decorator
```

(The `engine`  is used in `con=args[0]`)

Comment: "However, I need to somehow pass self.engine to the decorator." I don't understand why? How is it being used? As far as I can tell, the `loadfixtures` decorator doesn't come from `unittest`? :/

Comment: true, it is a custom decorator, but as it needs to write something to the database, it requires the (sqlalchemy/psycopg2) engine.  I'll add the decorator function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is actually passed as the first argument to `test_checkdb_employee`. So to access your `engine` in the decorator to use as argument for the `con` parameter you could just do `args[0].engine` with `args[0]` being `self` (the `TestCompany` instance).

```
def loadfixtures(files):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            for file in files: 
                df = pd.read_json(Path(datafolder).joinpath(file))
                df.to_sql(file.split(".")[0], con=args[0].engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_func
    return decorator
```

Comment: thanks. I knew I was close, but couldn't figure out the last step..

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.